# FxCop Custom Code analysis: check class reference in another class

Tags: .net, code-analysis, fxcop

I am writing a custom code analysis check wherein I need to check that the Model class in ASP .NET MVC application does not have reference of the controller class. But I am unable to find anything relevant to the same as to how to check that my controller for reference of the model class.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the visitor approach (http://binarycoder.net/fxcop/html/check_and_visit.html) to create your rule, you can override the `VisitMemberBinding` method to verify whether any members of a controller type are being accessed (assuming you have a way to identify whether a particular target type qualifies as a controller).

Comment: Hi Nicole, thanks for the answer. I think the solution provided by Patrick seems more easy to search for a similar kinda code in FxCop. However if that doesn't fits well, I would try to explore the solution as suggested by you. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The tool [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) for .NET developer is particularly suited to write this kind of static analysis checks (*Disclaimer: I belong to the team that develops NDepend*)

- *I am writing a custom code analysis check wherein I need to check that the Model class in ASP .NET MVC application does not have reference of the controller class*

NDepend lets write custom code rules through C# LINQ queries. Around [200 default code rules](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html) are provided. This LINQ syntax makes it straightforward to write the rule you are asking for:

```
warnif count > 0
let modelClasses = Application.Namespaces.WithNameLike("Model").ChildTypes()
let controllerClasses = Application.Namespaces.WithNameLike("Controller").ChildTypes()

from modelClass in modelClasses.UsingAny(controllerClasses)
select new { modelClass, 
             controllerClassesUsed = modelClass.TypesUsed.Intersect(controllerClasses) 
}
```

Obviously it is easy to tweak this rule, maybe you'd like to define *modelClasses* or *controllerClasses* through a different way (derive from a certain class, implement a certain interface...).

NDepend can be integrated in VS 2012, 2010, 2008 and has facility to edit LINQ rules, and browse their results live. Rules checking can also be integrated into your build process, and [rules violation ca be shown in a report](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CI_Report.aspx#CQLRule).

[image]

- *But I am unable to find anything relevant to the same as to how to check that my controller for reference of the model class.*

I am not sure to understand this requirement, do you mean that you want to write a rule to check that controller classes are indeed using model classes?

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for this solution. I would surely try to explore the same. As for your question, No I dont want to check whether controller classes are using model classes as that is expected out of the controller classes. I am just checking that any developer does not use a reference of controller class in the model classes of the application. I will try to search for similar something in FxCop as the suggested answer from you. Thanks.